# SQL, Unused LEFT JOINs slowing down, Optimizer not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-optimization

I have a simple SQL statement. Some of the LEFT JOINs aren't used in the result set. Why is MySQL 5.5 slowing down the execution on the second version of my SQL, although the JOINs are completely irrelevant for the result? Why isn't the LEFT JOIN being ignored?

Exectime: 0.03s (no JOINs)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(o.orderid), o.orderid
FROM
    customerorder o
LIMIT 0,20
```

Exectime: 0.20s (irrelevant JOINs)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(o.orderid), o.orderid
FROM
    customerorder o
    LEFT JOIN object o1 ON o1.objectid = o.orderid
    LEFT JOIN object o2 ON o2.objectid = o1.objectid
    LEFT JOIN object o3 ON o3.objectid = o2.objectid
    LEFT JOIN object o4 ON o4.objectid = o3.objectid
    LEFT JOIN object o5 ON o5.objectid = o4.objectid
LIMIT 0,20
```

**Edit/"Solution":** It's not being ignored, because the JOINs are relevant :-) They could increase the count(). So a solution to the problem is something like this:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (select count(*) from customerorder) as count, o.orderid
FROM
    customerorder o
    left JOIN object o1 ON o1.objectid = o.orderid
    left JOIN object o2 ON o2.objectid = o1.objectid
    left JOIN object o3 ON o3.objectid = o2.objectid
    left JOIN object o4 ON o4.objectid = o3.objectid
    left JOIN object o5 ON o5.objectid = o4.objectid
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: How would MySQL know that the JOINS are completely irrelevant for the result without executing the query with all the LEFT JOINS to see the result?

Comment: Shouldn't the optimizer recognize that the selected columns have nothing to do with the joined tables?

Comment: @xsign Great question, it's a matter of execution sequence. See below.

Comment: Brian is right. If one of the joins did resolve, regardless of the fact that you are only selecting from one table, it could make your COUNT higher. The join on O1 to O will short-circuit other joins if it returns nothing.

Comment: @DanielG that is an excellent point. Do you think MySQL would be able to determine from primary keys or indexing that the join would produce a 1:1 lookup and not bother? In my experience it's not so smart, but perhaps there is more under the hood than I recall.

Comment: @DanielG Ah... I totally missed that point...! Thanks. Btw: It's prim-key and 1:1. That's why I didn't see that one...

Comment: Yes, makes a lot of sense, xsign in a 1:1 scenario. @JNevill, I honestly don't know if the optimizer is smart enough to figure that out, but it sure seems like it should/could. :-)

Comment: MySQL is not generally considered the smartest RDBMS, its optimizer misses some obvious things and also does some very dumb things (take a look at how it explains `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE some condition)`)

Comment: @DanielG yeah... the trick is to resolve the count() as a subselect in the fields section... with that one it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the query optimizer has to perform all the joins before it even questions whether they're needed or not.

> Note: As eloquently pointed out by JNevill below that in execution, certain RDBMS systems will first parse the query, and evaluate data retrieval mechanisms based on the context of the query as whole. Avoiding the oversimplification of event execution below.

Order of execution:

```
1. FROM clause (JOIN is lumped in here)
2. WHERE clause
3. SELECT clause
4. GROUP BY clause
5. HAVING clause
6. ORDER BY clause
```

Comment: Not really understanding the downvote here? The answer is correct.

Comment: It's a very simplistic order of operations that doesn't take into account optimization. Although, given MySQL's craptacular optimization this may be as close as it needs to be.

Comment: @JNevill might be simplistic, but it's appropriate in this case.

Comment: In any other RDBMS (and mysql should be no exception) the actual query written isn't 1:1 executed in the database. Most products have an optimization engine that makes decisions about data retrieval after the parsing engine is done with it's job. Every other RDBMS would not bother with the joins in OP's query. MySQL is kind of dumb though and allows you enough rope to hang yourself with.

Comment: Is there any chance to give the optimizer a hint that he can ignore the JOINs?

Comment: @JNevill great information, and you're totally right in the end there.

Comment: @xsign another great question, I would say likely not.

Comment: Furthermore, if it's true MySQL lacks an optimization engine (I remember reading a long time ago that the DB attempts a bit of optimization, although poorly, and the rest is blindly handed over to the storage engine) then I would expect a good answer would be able to speak to that point. Namely, other RDBMS like Postgres, SQl Server, Teradata, Oracle, etc prioritize optimization, but MySQL splits the duty and sort of falls on it's face in situations like this.